# Expected number of ﬂips needed that at least two heads and one tail have been ﬂipped

Tags: probability, expected-value

The original question is shown below (References from the book of Introduction to Probability Models Tenth Edition):

> A coin, having probability $p$ of landing heads, is continually ﬂipped until at least one head and one tail have been ﬂipped.
>
> (a) Find the expected number of ﬂips needed.
>
> (d) Repeat part (a) in the case where ﬂipping is continued until a total of at least two heads and one tail have been ﬂipped.

I solve the question (a), but I am not sure my answer for question (d).

My answer is shown:

Let $N$ is the number of flips at least two head and one tail.

$$
\begin{align*}
E[N] &= E[E[N|Y]]\\ &= E[N|HH]P(H)P(H) + E[N|HT]P(H)P(T) + E[N|TH]P(T)P(H)
\end{align*}
$$

$E[N|HH]$ means the first two are heads until a tail appeared;

$E[N|HT]$ means the first two are head and tail until a head appeared;

$E[N|TH]$ means the first two are head and tail a head appeared;

Let $E[T] = 1/q = 1/1-p$, $E[H] = 1/p$

Then, $E[N] = (2+1/q)pp + (2+1/p)p(1-p) + (2+1/p)p(1-p)$ ←Ans.

I am not sure whether I am right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Plainly $E[N]\gt3$ but when $p=\frac12$ your final answer evaluates to $3$ so I don't think it can be right.

Comment: I get $E[N]=q(1+\frac2p)+pq(2+\frac1p)+p^2(2+\frac1q)$.

Comment: More neatly: $$E[N]=2\left(\frac1p-p\right)+\left(\frac1q-q\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @bof , I am think what is my state (three conditions) wrong.

Comment: Did you miss the case where the first two flips are TT?

Comment: Thanks @bof. I will try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q=1-p$, $P=1/p$, and $Q=1/q$ for convenience.  Some brief scratch paper work will verify that $pP=qQ=1$, $pQ=Q-1$, and $qP=P-1$.

Let's solve part (a) first, since it will be useful. Your first flip is either heads or tails.  If it is heads, then we expect it will take $Q$ flips for the first tails to come up. If it is tails, then we expect it will take $P$ flips for the first heads to come up.  Therefore, if $A$ is the expected number of flips before we see both heads and tails, then 
$$E[A]=p(1+Q)+q(1+P)\\=p+pQ+q+qP\\=1+(Q-1)+(P-1)=P+Q-1\\=(P-p)+(Q-q)$$

The same effort applies to the second part.  Your first flip is either heads or tails.  If it is heads, then we expect it will take $A$ flips to get another head and a tail. If it is tails, then we expect it will take $2P$ flips for two heads to come up.  Therefore,
$$E[B]=p(1+E[A])+q(1+2P)\\=p(P+Q)+q(1+2P)\\=pP+pQ+q+2qP
\\=1+(Q-1)+q+2(P-1)\\=Q+q+2P-2\\=Q+q+2P-(2p+2q)\\=2P-2p+Q-q=2(P-p)+(Q-q)$$

Thanks to bof for recognizing that this collapses into an elegant form.

Comment: I think it simplifies to $E[B]=2(P-p)+(Q-q)$.

Comment: If the second head comes on the $X$th flip, and the first tail comes on the $Y$th flip, and $Z=\min(X,Y)$, then $B=X+Y-Z$, so $$E[B]=E[X]+E[Y]-E[Z]=\frac2p+\frac1q-(1+p)=\frac2p+\frac1q-(2p+q)=2\left(\frac1p-p\right)+\left(\frac1q-q\right)$$

Comment: @bof I updated my solution to algebraically verify your conjecture.  I really wasn't expecting it!

Comment: Thanks a lot to reply my question, I am learning it. : D Good understand~

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the probability of heads $(0\lt p\lt1)$ and $q=1-p$ the probability of tails.

Define random variables $W,X,Y,Z$ as follows: $W$ is the number of flips until you have flipped at least two heads and one tail; the second head comes on the $X^\text{th}$ flip; the first tail comes on the $Y^\text{th}$ flip; and $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Then $W=\max(X,Y)=X+Y-\min(X,Y)=X+Y-Z$, so
$$E[W]=E[X+Y-Z]=E[X]+E[Y]-E[Z]=\frac2p+\frac1q-(1+p)$$$$=\frac2p+\frac1q-(2p+q)=2\left(\frac1p-p\right)+\left(\frac1q-q\right)=\frac2p+\frac{p^2}q.$$

**More generally,** if $W_{m,n}$ is the number of flips until you have flipped at least $m$ heads and $n$ tails,
$$E[W_{m,n}]=\frac mp+\frac nq-\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{i+j}ip^iq^j$$
and in particular
$$E[W_{m,1}]=\frac mp+\frac{p^m}q.$$